# Retrieve SQLite Data by using Date part out of DateTime Format

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I want to retrieve the date from sqlite by using date. But by default the column in sqlite inserted is datetime format.

For instance,this is my Type Table

_id       date_value

1        2015-07-06T11:36:35

2        2015-07-06T12:10:10

3        2015-07-06T12:10:19

4        2015-07-03T17:13:59

5        2015-07-03T17:14:04

6        2015-07-03T17:14:27

I want to retrieve the data by using date only. How do i want to query?

I tried to retrieve like this: Select * from Type where date_value=date('2015-07-03T17:13:59')
It returns zero rows.

I need all rows where the date(2015-07-03) matched

Expected result:
_id date_value

4   2015-07-03T17:14:27

5   2015-07-03T17:14:04

6   2015-07-03T17:14:27

How should i achieve this output?

Comment: You're Date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @MD, i want to retreive all data from sql by using date only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date()` function simply returns the date part of its parameter, so the result of `date('2015-07-03T17:13:59')` is `'2015-07-03'`. This value does not match any of the values in the `date_value` column.

You need to extract the date from the values in the `date_value` column:

```
Select * from Type where date(date_value) = '2015-07-03'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use SimpleDateFormat to format the Date as a String:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

String todayAsString = dateFormat.format(today);
String tomorrowAsString = dateFormat.format(tomorrow);

System.out.println(todayAsString);
System.out.println(tomorrowAsString);

Prints:

2015-07-03 16:14:27
2015-08-03 16:14:27
```